# different behavior for OPTIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT in Hibernate 5.6.9.Final vs 3.6.10

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am in the process of migrating from Hibernate 3.6.10 to 5.6.9.

I notice a behavior difference between these two versions if it comes to the usage of the OPTIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT lock on an entity.

Let's say that I have an existing entity with a version=0. If I then do the following:

1. load the entity through the EntityManager (version=0)
2. Apply the OPTIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT lock on the entity
3. Modify the entity through a setter of an attribute
4. Create new entity and set attribute after persist and flush the entity

For 3.6.10, the version is not incremented (version=1). For version 5.6.9 the version is incremented (version=2)

Following are my code snippet

```
package com.example.service.impl;

import com.example.models.Item;
import com.example.service.ItemService;

import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.LockModeType;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@Service
public class ItemServiceImpl implements ItemService {

@PersistenceContext 
private EntityManager em;

@Override
@Transactional
public Item save(Item entity) {
    entity = new Item();
    entity.setName(getItemName());
    entity.setInUse(true);
    em.persist(entity);
    em.flush();
    return entity;
}

@Override
@Transactional
public Item update(Long id) {
    Item itm = em.find(Item.class, id);
    em.lock(itm, LockModeType.OPTIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT);
    if (itm!=null) {
        itm.setInUse(false);
        Item entity = new Item();
        entity.setName(getItemName());
        entity.setInUse(true);
        em.persist(entity);
        em.flush();
        return entity;
    }
    return null;
}

private String getItemName() {
    byte[] array = new byte[7]; 
    new Random().nextBytes(array);
    return new String(array, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
}
```

}

For , itm entity the version is set to 2 instead of 1 in the Hibernate 5.6.9.Final  and in the hibernate 3.6.10 is working properly fine. It is updating version 1.

All help is appreciated! Thanks in advance, Kind regards, Pratik Panchal